# parsing/escape in Swift

Tags: html, regex, swift, parsing

Currently i have a html string (here is a part of it) in swift where i want to escape a special part

```
<tr style="color:White;background-color:#32B4FA;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;font-weight:normal;">
    <th scope="col" style="border-color:Black;font-family:Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:X-Small;width:25px;">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col" style="border-color:Black;font-family:Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:X-Small;width:20px;">Park-<br>stätte</th><th scope="col" style="border-color:Black;font-family:Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:X-Small;width:25px;">Parkmöglichkeit</th><th scope="col" style="border-color:Black;font-family:Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:X-Small;width:25px;">Anzahl Stellplätze</th><th scope="col" style="border-color:Black;font-family:Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:X-Small;width:25px;">Freie Stellplätze</th>
</tr>
<tr style="color:#000066;">
    <td align="center" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;font-size:X-Small;width:25px;">
        <span id="GridView1__Id_0" title="Kennzeichen" ReadOnly="true" style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;font-family:Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:X-Small;width:25px;">P1</span> 
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;font-size:X-Small;">
        <img src="Images/Symbol_Tiefgarage.jpg" style="width:20px;" />
    </td>
    <td align="left" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;font-size:Small;">
        <a id="GridView1_HyperLink1_0" href="http://www.paderborn.de/microsite/asp/parken_in_der_city/TG_Koenigsplatz.php" target="_top" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:X-Small;width:150px;">Königsplatz</a>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;font-size:X-Small;width:40px;">                   
        <span id="GridView1__AnzahlPlaetze_0" title="Anzahl Plätze" ReadOnly="true" style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;font-family:Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:X-Small;">810</span> 
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;font-size:Smaller;width:40px;">
        <span id="GridView1__AnzahlFreiePlaetze_0" title="Freie Plätze" ReadOnly="true" style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;font-family:Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:X-Small;">0</span> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

the Part for me that is interesting is the "810"( could be 0-1000 or a text string) from

```
 <td align="center" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;font-size:X-Small;width:40px;">                   
        <span id="GridView1__AnzahlPlaetze_0" title="Anzahl Plätze" ReadOnly="true" style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;font-family:Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:X-Small;">810</span> 
    </td>
```

i did try to get use to regEx but this did not work out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a XML/HTML parser which supports CSS selectors to retrieve that string, since the span that contains that string has a id = "GridView1__AnzahlPlaetze_0", and you can use query "#GridView1__AnzahlPlaetze_0" to retrieve it.

For example, with a Swift library called [Fuzi](https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi) that wraps libxml2

```
import Fuzi
let doc = try? HTMLDocument(string: htmlString)
if let result = doc?.firstChild(css: "#GridView1__AnzahlPlaetze_0") {
    print(result.stringValue)
}
```

The above code is tested.

Comment: thanks as a "noob" i still try to figure out how to "add Fuzi" to my project as i never worked with pod/Carthage

Comment: it is included in the README, it shouldn't take you too long and you will fall in love with these tools since they are so convenient.